# How to get Firefox instances launched by Selenium server to remember form history?

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-rc

I have a special profile for my Selenium server with various form history in it, and when I launch Firefox regularly I can indeed use them. However, when Selenium server launches a Firefox instance from this profile, there is no trace of them (although the regular browser history appears just fine).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `reuseBrowserSession` command line parameter when launching Selenium RC, retains session details between browser launches.

Comment: When I use this parameter, at least on my OS X 10.6 + FF 3.6.8 setup, there seems to be no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save it as JSON or YAML or .properties file?